# Customize em dash (output only)

Tags: xetex, punctuation

I've got a lot of text like this:

```
---~Вот мои верительные грамоты. Открывайте ворота!

---~Погодите\ldots{}~---~Губы лейтенанта затряслись.~---~Что такое?..

---~Для человека, получившего офицерский патент от Императора,
вы очень плохо умеете разговаривать со старшими.
```

or this:

```
It is a
common ailment of those who have studied some Spanish---and \emph{know}
what they want to say---but lack conversational practice.
```

By default, three dashes get replaced with the em dash. Suppose I'd like to replace it with something a shade shorter, yet still longer than the en dash. And I *don't* want to use macro definitions, because they make a text with a lot of dashes look too ugly.

Is there a way to translate `---` into whatever I wish, optionally?

I use XeTeX.